# Error: Cannot find module './algs'

Tags: node.js, module, npm, npm-install

When trying to run a nodejs server I keep getting this error for a missing module './algs'. Does anyone know which module I need to install to get this to work?

Error :

```
$ node index
module.js:457
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './algs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:<file path>\node_modules\sshpk\lib\key.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "Stock",
  "version": "0.2.5",
  "description": "Stock website",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.9.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "ejs": "2.4.1",
    "express": "4.13.3",
    "firebase": "^3.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "watson-developer-cloud": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "<git url>"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I have tried `npm install algs` and `./algs` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I don't think it's about `algs` module or if there any module called `algs`.

A similar thing happened to me today. I was using `event-stream` with `gulp` and trying to concat two streams. While running the code, I saw some random module `error` like yours and the funny thing is I didn't even use that random module in my code. Then I looked closely and found that I am missing a **comma** in between two streams. I guess the module which shown missing by the `error`, was a dependency for `event-stream` (module that I have used).

I am not saying you maid mistake like me but taking a close look may help you.